# how to sort data from a specific column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to collect the data from a specific sheet and then sort those data using a specific column.

When I try to use the function `.sort()`, it works, but I'am not able to specify the column.

So I have been visiting this :

- [sort](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).

But it didn't really help me. I understand that I have to create a function to go into the `()` of the `.sort()`, but I don't know how do it have to look like.

I want to sort the data that I pick alphabetically, using the value of the column B.

here si the code I did so far :

```
function FILL_PROJ_005() {


  var DATA_COLLECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
  var PROJECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PROJECT");


  var DATA_COLLECTStartRow = 6;
  var DATA_COLLECTColumnCount = 1;
  var lrDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var rangeDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getRange(DATA_COLLECTStartRow,1,lrDATA_COLLECT-DATA_COLLECTStartRow,5);
  var DATA_COLLECT = rangeDATA_COLLECT.getValues();

  var DATA_FILTERED = DATA_COLLECT.filter(r => r[0] != ""); 

  var DATA_SORTED = DATA_FILTERED.sort();//sort in column (2) 

  PROJECTsheet.getRange(1,1,DATA_SORTED.length,5).setValues(DATA_SORTED);

}
```

and here a sample of the data I'am working on :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | BELVEDERE MUSEUM | 31.5 | ANTHONY |
| 2D | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 161 | MAREIKE |
| PROJECT MANAGEMENT | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 22 | ANTHONY |
|  | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 183 | ANTHONY |
| 2D | DHM BERLIN | 5 | MAREIKE |
|  | DHM BERLIN | 5 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW | 50 | MAREIKE |
| RECHERCHES | EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW | 3 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ | 7 | ANTHONY |
|  | BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ | 7 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 48 | MAREIKE |
| COMMUNICATION | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 4 | MAREIKE |
|  | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 52 | MAREIKE |

and here is what I want at the end :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2D | BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ | 7 | ANTHONY |
| 2D | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 48 | MAREIKE |
| COMMUNICATION | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 4 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 161 | MAREIKE |
| PROJECT MANAGEMENT | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 22 | ANTHONY |
| 2D | DHM BERLIN | 5 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW | 50 | MAREIKE |
| RECHERCHES | EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW | 3 | MAREIKE |

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Especially, I cannot understand `sort the column number 2 of a 5 column data array`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situation you expect using your showing input table? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: How do  you wish to sort the data? ... numerically or lexicographically ? range.sort((a,b) => {return  a[0]-b}[0] sorts the data  in the range numerically by the first column in the range.  In this case the data is a two dimensional array and each element of the array is a row and each index represents one of the columns in the row. With zero representing column one.

Comment: I have try to clarify my needs and add a table of my purpose ! hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

```js
function FILL_PROJ_005() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DATA_COLLECTsheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
  var PROJECTsheet = ss.getSheetByName("PROJECT");
  var DATA_COLLECTStartRow = 6;
  var DATA_COLLECTColumnCount = 1;
  var lrDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var rangeDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getRange(DATA_COLLECTStartRow, 1, lrDATA_COLLECT - DATA_COLLECTStartRow, 5);
  var DATA_COLLECT = rangeDATA_COLLECT.getValues();
  var DATA_FILTERED = DATA_COLLECT.filter(r => r[0] != "");
  PROJECTsheet.getRange(1, 1, DATA_FILTERED.length, 5).setValues(DATA_FILTERED).sort([{ column: 2, ascending: true }, { column: 1, ascending: true }]); // or PROJECTsheet.getRange(1, 1, DATA_FILTERED.length, 5).setValues(DATA_FILTERED).sort([{ column: 2 }, { column: 1 }]);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

```js
function FILL_PROJ_005() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DATA_COLLECTsheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
  var PROJECTsheet = ss.getSheetByName("PROJECT");
  var DATA_COLLECTStartRow = 6;
  var DATA_COLLECTColumnCount = 1;
  var lrDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var rangeDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getRange(DATA_COLLECTStartRow, 1, lrDATA_COLLECT - DATA_COLLECTStartRow, 5);
  var DATA_COLLECT = rangeDATA_COLLECT.getValues();
  var DATA_FILTERED = DATA_COLLECT.filter(r => r[0] != "");
  var DATA_SORTED = DATA_FILTERED.sort((a, b) => a[0] < b[0] ? 1 : -1).sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1);
  PROJECTsheet.getRange(1, 1, DATA_SORTED.length, 5).setValues(DATA_SORTED);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your sample input table, `RECHERCHES   DIVERSES EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW 3   MAREIKE` is used. But, in your output table, `RECHERCHES    EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW  3   MAREIKE`. If the sample input table uses `RECHERCHES    EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW  3   MAREIKE`, it seems that the modified script can obtain your expected output situation.

#### References:

- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)

Comment: I'am sorry about the `RECHERCHES    EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW  3   MAREIKE`, I did the table manually, and I think I made a mistake, I edit and correct it right know !

Comment: @emilianoSala Thank you for replying. When you tested my proposed 2 patterns and those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: the modified script 2 is definitly what I wanted to do ! thx !